# write to multiple files line by line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe example

```
first   second
1       3
2       4
5       6
```

I'm iterating through the dataframe line by line performing subtraction and addition. I wanna write the outputs to new csv files respectively line by line. 
I'm not sure how I can write to multiple csv files directly.

For single file I use something like

```
with open(subtract_output_file, "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in df.iterrows():
        a = row[1][0]
        b = row[1][1]
        writer.writerow(a-b)
```

I want to write the addition output to another file simultaneously as I don't wanna read the input twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open multiple files at once by doing:

```py
with open(output_file_1, 'w') as f1, open(output_file_2, 'w') as f2:
    do_something()
```

So for your code it'd be something like...

```py
with open(subtract_output_file, "w") as csvsub, open(addition_output_file, 'w') as csvadd:
    writersub = csv.DictWriter(csvsub, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writeradd = csv.DictWriter(csvadd, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writersub.writeheader()
    writeradd.writeheader()
    for row in df.iterrows():
        a = row[1][0]
        b = row[1][1]
        writersub.writerow(a-b)
        writeradd.writerow(a+b)
```

This might not be the most efficient way but should work.

Answer (score 1):

Why using *pandas* and don't take its advantage? Four clear commands altogether:

```
plus  = df["first"] + df["second"]
minus = df["first"] - df["second"] 

plus .to_csv("addition_output_file", header=["plus"],  index=False)
minus.to_csv("subtract_output_file", header=["minus"], index=False)
```

- Vectorized `+` and `-` operations are much faster than your `for` loop.
- The series' `.to_csv()` method does all “dirty” work.
- No need to write row by rows simultaneously — no reading the input twice.